# ImportError: No module named 'elasticsearch'

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch, jupyter-notebook

I'm working with a cohort's python script, which calls on the elasticsearch module. However, when I run it in Jupyter, I get the following error:

```
ImportError Traceback (most recent call last)
in ()
2 for i in range(0,6):
3 print('working on page: %d' %(i+1))
----> 4 ingester(url_base+str(i*50))
5

in ingester(string)
5 import re
6 import time
----> 7 from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
8 es = Elasticsearch()
9 #start session s

ImportError: No module named 'elasticsearch'
```

I'm using python 3.6 and jupyter is using the python 3 kernel. I've already installed the elasticsearch module by typing "sudo pip install elasticsearch" at the command line (this is on Ubuntu) and even did a restart just to be on the safe side.

If it helps, the entirety of the code is at:

https://pastebin.com/g9MVQ5Dm

(the login info has obviously been changed)

When I try to run it directly from the command line, it gives me the same error but with urllib3. This is kind of confusing, but I can only deal with one problem at a time.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Check that your `pip` is installing Python 3 modules. You may have just installed the Python 2 version by accident.

Comment: That's a good point; however, I noticed that the pip install notes indicated that the files were going into a 3.5 folder.